# Probability of CD track played on a particular position

Tags: probability, statistics

There are 8 songs on a CD which a are played in a random order. What is the probability that there will be none/one track that will be played in the position specified on the CD cover?

Any approach suggestions on solving this problem?

Comment: Here is an approach: Use the *inclusion/exclusion* principle in order to calculate the probability of the **complementary** event, and then calculate $1$ minus that probability.

Comment: You need the number of permutations with $0$ fixpoints and of those with $1$ fixpoint.

Comment: When I fix a point then I have 7! permutations right?

Comment: Interesting, related fact: as the number of tracks increases, the probability that some (at least one) track will be in its correct place approaches $\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: @craaaft No, a fix point means a point with $\sigma(n)=n$. But you are not completely wrong. You can fix some point to be correct, but then you have to count the number of permutations with $7$ objects and no fix point. This result, muliplied with $8$, will be the number of permutations with $8$ objects and exactly one fix point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your cd is not on repeat ;)

1) i would compute how much possible outcome of played track can happen (isn't that 8! ?)

2) i would calculate the probability of having one track played at the right place (lets do the first one)

-> first one is fixed, then the second one can be any out of 6 (because it cannot play the one of its own track) (isn't this 6! ?)
so a total of 8 tracks * 6!

3) then add the probability of 0 track  (1st one can be any out of 7, 2nd one any out of 6 remaining... so 7!)

4) sum everything together
(8*6!+7!) /8! which gives roughly 1/4

Comment: And in case of doubt, a simulation would solve anything :)